# Why doesn't Vim execute my column setting in this command?

Tags: vim, macvim

I have a Vim command to enter a "Distraction Free" mode:

```
command! DistractionFreeMode set guioptions-=r gfn=Cousine:h12 showtabline=0 fullscreen laststatus=0 noruler wrap linebreak nolist linespace=5 foldcolumn=3 nonumber columns=80
```

Note also that I am using MacVim.  The command sort of works, but some of the settings don't seem to be triggered.  These include `columns=80` and `nolist`.  I always have to set these separately after executing this command in order to get them right.  I have also tried putting these settings in a function that I called with the command and had the same issue.  What is the source of this problem?

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of the look I'm aiming at.  Using `fullscreen` and `columns` together is necessary to achieve this, as far as I know:

[image]

Comment: You have columns=80 and fullscreen in there at the same time. These two commands probably arn't playing nicely with each other. Are you sure you want both of them there? I also can't reproduce nolist not being activated. Check to see if you have any autocmd that activate list.

Comment: @FDinoff Hmm, now I can't reproduce the `nolist` not being set either... So forget about that one (but thank you for checking!).  Yes, I do want columns and fullscreen to be together.  It's necessary for the look that I'm including in the screenshot (which I'm now posting) to above.  And they seem to work together perfectly fine when I set columns after running the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According for the help for fullscreen (`:h fullscreen`) There are option to tailor the behavior of what happens when you enter fullscreen mode which are set with `fuoptions`

On my MacVim fuoptions is set to

```
fuoptions=maxvert,maxhotz
```

When we look at `:h fuoptions`

```
    maxvert When entering fullscreen, 'lines' is set to the maximum number
            of lines fitting on the screen in fullscreen mode. When
            leaving fullscreen, if 'lines' is still equal to the maximized
            number of lines, it is restored to the value it had before
            entering fullscreen.
    maxhorz When entering fullscreen, 'columns' is set to the maximum number
            of columns fitting on the screen in fullscreen mode. When
            leaving fullscreen, if 'columns' is still equal to the maximized
            number of columns, it is restored to the value it had before
            entering fullscreen.
```

This mean that when you enter fullscreen mode MacVim resizes to to the maximum number of lines and columns it can. (ignoring the values you set)

To fix this you can either add `set fuoption-=maxhorz` to remove the offending option or add `set=maxvert` to force it to only use maxvert regardless if other options are set. This stops MacVim from overriding your settings in the horizontal direction.

So your fixed command would look something like

```
command! DistractionFreeMode set guioptions-=r gfn=Cousine:h12 showtabline=0 fuoptions-=maxhorz fullscreen laststatus=0 noruler wrap linebreak nolist linespace=5 foldcolumn=3 nonumber columns=80
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks so much.  I should have known better and read the help